# How to use options object in Javascript's Function

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I am trying this to get input as an argument with some objects,

```
function write(param) {

 var str = param.str;
 var elem = param.elem; 
 document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML= str;
}
```

and I'm passing this as an argument,

```
write({
   elem:"op",
   str:"Hello"
});
```

The thing I have to do is that I am having font tag with id 'op',

```
<font id="op"></font>
```

and when I run this I wont print **Hello**, as I have given **Hello** as an object parameter with **op** element for output.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsbin.com/solalefuba/edit?html,js,output). Maybe don't use `font`, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm seeing it, your code works as intended.

**Answer for using an options object on a function:**

In ES6 default parameters can prevent values to be undefined, however it does not actually compensate for the case that you're passing an object with missing parameters.

In this case I would suggest using `Object.assign()`:

```
function write(options){
   options = Object.assign({}, {
       myDefaultParam: 'Hello',
       elem: null,
       str: ''
   }, options);

   if(options.elem) document.getElementById(options.elem).innerHTML = options.str;
}
```

What `Object.assign()` does is to merge a object of default options with the provided functions, allowing you to set default parameters that you can rely on. In this case `write({})` would result in options being this object:

```
{
   myDefaultParam: 'Hello',
   elem: null,
   str: ''    
}
```

If this is overkill for you, I would suggest to simply check wether the keys are defined on your `param` object like this:

```
function write(param){
   if(!param || !param.elem || !param.str) return false;
   return document.getElementById(param.elem).innerHTML = param.str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where exactly your code has gone wrong. Here you can see that both the javascript and the html you produced should work together just fine.

```js
function write(param) {

  var str = param.str;
  var elem = param.elem;
  document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = str;
}

write({
  elem: 'op',
  str: 'Hello'
})
```

```html
<font id="op"></font>
```

Comment: There is a close reason for non-reproducible.